# convert a tsv file to xls/xlsx using python

Tags: python, xls, file-conversion, csv

I want to convert a file in tsv format to xls/xlsx..

I tried using

```
os.rename("sample.tsv","sample.xlsx")
```

But the file getting converted is corrupted. Is there any other method of doing it?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple example of converting TSV to XLSX using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and the core csv module:

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Add some command-line logic to read the file names.
tsv_file = 'sample.tsv'
xlsx_file = 'sample.xlsx'

# Create an XlsxWriter workbook object and add a worksheet.
workbook = Workbook(xlsx_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a TSV file reader.
tsv_reader = csv.reader(open(tsv_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t')

# Read the row data from the TSV file and write it to the XLSX file.
for row, data in enumerate(tsv_reader):
    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)

# Close the XLSX file.
workbook.close()
```

Comment: in python3, it works when changing to `csv.reader(open(tsv_file,'rt'),delimiter="\t")`

Answer (score 1):

You need:

1. Read the data from the `tsv` file.
2. Convert it in what you want them to be.
3. Write them to an Excel file with [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) for `xlsx` or [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/) for `xls`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Add some command-line logic to read the file names.
tsv_file = 'sample.tsv'
xlsx_file = 'sample.xlsx'

# Create an XlsxWriter workbook object and add a worksheet.
workbook = Workbook(xlsx_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a TSV file reader.
tsv_reader = csv.reader(open(tsv_file,'rt'),delimiter="\t")

# Read the row data from the TSV file and write it to the XLSX file.
for row, data in enumerate(tsv_reader):
    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)

# Close the XLSX file.
workbook.close()
```