# How to read input to python in bash

Tags: python, bash

I have code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852655/convert-a-tsv-file-to-xls-xlsx-using-python) and I would like to use this python script in bash like:

> python conversion.py sample.tsv sample.xlsx

python script:

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

# Add some command-line logic to read the file names.
tsv_file = 'sample.tsv'
xlsx_file = 'sample.xlsx'

# Create an XlsxWriter workbook object and add a worksheet.
workbook = Workbook(xlsx_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a TSV file reader.
tsv_reader = csv.reader(open(tsv_file, 'rb'), delimiter='\t')

# Read the row data from the TSV file and write it to the XLSX file.
for row, data in enumerate(tsv_reader):
    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, data)

# Close the XLSX file.
workbook.close()
```

How can I modify this python script. Sorry for the maybe stupid question, but I do not work with python.

Comment: `import sys`, `tsv_file = sys.argv[1]`, `xlsx_file = sys.argv[2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

....

tsv_file = sys.argv[1]

xlsx_file = sys.argv[2]

...

You can run like:

```
main.py sample.tsv sample.xlsx
```

You also can check argparse package. It provides much fancy functions. It is basically a wraper of sys.argv.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply - I have this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversion_xlsx.py", line 5, in <module>
    tsv_file = sys.argv[1]
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined, Any  idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: I forgot import sys.. Thank you so much.